# Внедрение ссылки в сообщение telegram bot без всплывающего окна при выводе

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Я работаю над телеграмм ботом с библиотекой **aiogram**. Использую **Markdown-разметку**.

**Мне нужно, чтобы при выводе выдавался текст с внедренной в слово ссылкой без дополнительной информации о передаваемом в ссылке сайте. Как это сделать?** (фото прикрепляю ниже)

Ссылку на слово у меня сделать получается, но дополнительную информацию мне видеть не нужно (она является лишней), так как может занимать ***много места*** в телеграмме

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['Python'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Hello Python! [python](https://www.python.org/)", parse_mode="Markdown")
```

[[image]]

**Заранее спасибо!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После parse_mode добавьте дополнительный параметр

```
disable_web_page_preview=True
```

Comment: Не могу Вас не поблагодарить :-) Большое спасибо!